# how to change theme of dynamicaly added li item jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

i tried change selected li item something like>

```
$("#subtypeId"+key+"").closest('li').attr('data-theme','e');
$("#subtypeId"+key+"").closest('li').attr('data-icon','plus');
```

But this seems  not work correctly (theme attr is changed in code but color theme is same ).

Is any possibility how to do easy, without messy code (remove and replacing items)?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have you tried executing something like `$(the_ul_element).listview('refresh')` after modifying your list? Is "#subtypeId"+key the `ul` element?

Comment: Yes, sure.Code is below:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZpDv6/

Answer (score 0):

You could change the JQM data-icon and data-theme with the following way:

```
$("#subtypeId"+key+"").closest('li').jqmData('icon','plus');
$("#subtypeId"+key+"").closest('li').jqmData('theme','e');
```

BR,
Tolis

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it not working. Attributes are changed in HTML, but change is not vissible.

Comment: Please post your HTML and explain what you want to do. The link you gave does not contain the HTML.